# How to generate a valid query for GET request from a nested array by "guzzle"?

Tags: api, guzzle

I want to send get-query to API by guzzle. If I use this approach

```
$test = [

        'unum' => '0256',
        'size' => 'size',
        'dough' => 'dough'
    ];
$response = $this->guzzleClient->get('ajax/getprice.php?for_send=', [
            'query' => $test
        ]);
```

it works finest.
 But if I want to send a nested array, like that:

```
$test = [
    [
        'unum' => '0256',
        'size' => 'big',
        'dough' => 'thin'
    ],
    [
        'unum' => '0256',
        'size' => 'big',
        'dough' => 'thin'
    ]

];
$response = $this->guzzleClient->get('ajax/getprice.php?for_send=', [
    'query' => $test
]);
```

It doesn't work.
But I'm sure the API accepts such requests(looks like this `ajax/getid.php?for_send=%5B%7B%22unum%22%3A%220141%22%2C%22dough%22%3A%22%D0%9F%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%22%2C%22size%22%3A%22%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8F%2C%2035%20%D1%81%D0%BC%22%7D%2C%7B%22unum%22%3A%220256%22%2C%22dough%22%3A%22%D0%9F%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%22%2C...`)

How can I generate valid `query` from a nested array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your example, the API accepts JSON inside `for_send` parameter, so simply encode your array as JSON:

```
$test = [
    [
        'unum' => '0256',
        'size' => 'Большая, 35 см',
        'dough' => 'Тонкое тесто'
    ],
    // ...
];
$response = $this->guzzleClient->get('ajax/getprice.php', [
    'query' => ['for_send' => json_encode($test)]
]);
```